# C# how to shorten multiple If expressions

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, if-statement

I have multiple validation boolean properties which can be required or not. If they are required they need to be checked for validation purposes. Therefore I had to build multiple if statements to handle each property. My question is if is there a better way to maintain this instead of having to write if for every new property.

```
public class ProductionNavbarViewModel
{
    public bool IsProductionActive { get; set; }
    public bool ValidatedComponents { get; set; }
    public bool ValidatedGeometries { get; set; }
    public bool ValidatedPokayokes { get; set; }
    public bool ValidatedTechnicalFile { get; set; }
    public bool ValidatedStandardOperationSheet { get; set; }
    public bool ValidatedOperationMethod { get; set; }
    public bool IsComponentsRequired { get; set; }
    public bool IsGeometriesRequired { get; set; }
    public bool IsPokayokesRequired { get; set; }
    public bool IsTechnicalFileRequired { get; set; }
    public bool IsStandardOperationSheetRequired { get; set; }
    public bool IsOperationMethodRequired { get; set; }


    public bool IsProductionReadyToStart()
    {
        if (IsComponentsRequired)
        {
            return ValidatedComponents;
        }

        if (IsComponentsRequired && IsGeometriesRequired)
        {
            return ValidatedComponents && ValidatedGeometries;
        }

        if (IsComponentsRequired && IsGeometriesRequired && IsPokayokesRequired)
        {
            return ValidatedComponents && ValidatedGeometries && ValidatedPokayokes;
        }

        if (IsComponentsRequired && IsGeometriesRequired && IsPokayokesRequired && IsTechnicalFileRequired)
        {
            return ValidatedComponents && ValidatedGeometries && ValidatedPokayokes && ValidatedTechnicalFile;
        }

        if (IsComponentsRequired && IsGeometriesRequired && IsPokayokesRequired && IsTechnicalFileRequired && ValidatedStandardOperationSheet)
        {
            return ValidatedComponents && ValidatedGeometries && ValidatedPokayokes && ValidatedTechnicalFile && ValidatedStandardOperationSheet;
        }

        if (IsComponentsRequired && IsGeometriesRequired && IsPokayokesRequired && IsTechnicalFileRequired && IsStandardOperationSheetRequired && IsOperationMethodRequired)
        {
            return ValidatedComponents && ValidatedGeometries && ValidatedPokayokes && ValidatedTechnicalFile && ValidatedStandardOperationSheet && ValidatedOperationMethod;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

There was a problem while making this code. The intended is to validate all options, they must be necessary, it cannot return if just one property meets the condition.

Thanks everyone, I will try some of the suggested approaches on the comments and I'll post the results after

**UPDATE**

I have come with a short version for now and more readable based on everyones comments until I can try every approach. Edited to combine all expressions as per @Alexander Powolozki answer.

```
    public bool IsProductionReadyToStart()
    {
        bool isValid = true;

        isValid &= !IsComponentsRequired || ValidatedComponents;
        isValid &= !IsGeometriesRequired || ValidatedGeometries;
        isValid &= !IsPokayokesRequired || ValidatedComponents;
        isValid &= !IsTechnicalFileRequired || ValidatedTechnicalFile;
        isValid &= !IsStandardOperationSheetRequired || ValidatedStandardOperationSheet;
        isValid &= !IsOperationMethodRequired || ValidatedOperationMethod;            

        return isValid;
    }
```

Comment: `bool option1 = IsComponentsRequired && ValidatedComponents; bool option2 = IsComponentsRequired && IsGeometriesRequired && ValidatedComponents && ValidatedGeometries; return option1 || option2;`

Comment: Your example might be flawed. If `IsComponentsRequired` is `true` you will always return `ValidatedComponents` and if it is `false` you will always return `false`.

Comment: @Ackdari Why is that flawed?

Comment: It means the entire example can be reduced to `return IsComponentsRequired && ValidatedComponents`, which is presumably not what the OP intended

Comment: @Ackdari how ? I just need return ValidatedComponents result, in the end it will always return false if any check has failed

Comment: @Ackdari Oh yeah your right...

Comment: @Jackal like canton7 pointed out, this example only _really_ cares for the first if.

Comment: OP, I think you meant to check the longest condition _first_?

Comment: @Ackdari that's true i didn't think well about this. All options can be required or optional and don't depend on each other, besides the IsRequired and Validated respective property

Comment: @Jackal then please update the example to reflect what you really want to do

Comment: A bitflag enum with a dictionary of enum -> func is what this makes me think of. Honestly though, in most scenarios I'd stick with the `if` code if it is clear enough.

Comment: @Jackal keep in mind that having many conditions like in your case by combining them the readability and maintainability of the code will be highly reduced, that's why i would recommend to let your code as it currently is because imho it's a good compromise between maintability and compactness

Comment: @Jackal The code in your update isn't going to work, the results of the last statement will override all previous results. You can fix this by changing `=` to `&=` like I did in my answer.

Comment: @JoostK thanks for the suggestion, forgot that if last one is true all the previous false ones will be ignored

Comment: @Jackal the first assignment of the isValid must be true and not false or all following will not be respected.

Comment: @Jackal Even with your updated code, the last statement will override everything no matter the outcome. Your code will work exactly the same if the previous 5 lines weren't there. If that last statement is special that overrides everything it should be handled differently, maybe as a if statement around it.

Comment: @JoostK I edited again to `&=`, missed it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct implementation of the method should be something like following:

```
public bool IsProductionReadyToStart()
{
    bool isValid = true;

    isValid &= !IsComponentsRequired || ValidatedComponents;
    isValid &= !IsGeometriesRequired || ValidatedGeometries;
    isValid &= !IsPokayokesRequired || ValidatedPokayokes;
    isValid &= !IsTechnicalFileRequired || ValidatedTechnicalFile;
    isValid &= !IsStandardOperationSheetRequired || ValidatedStandardOperationSheet;
    isValid &= !IsOperationMethodRequired || ValidatedOperationMethod;            

    return isValid;
}
```

when not uing &= then you erase all previous results you checked instead of combine them.

Comment: OP said in the comments that his example is not what he wanted to do

Comment: @Ackadri yes but his initial implementation is equivalent to my code. Unfortunally i havent seen your comments to which i fully agree

Comment: This approach is good from writer perspective, but is a "nightmare" for a reader. As a reader I need to read all lines to understand what is the logic behind final result (not mentioning negated conditions). For example @PavelAnikhouski second approach would do exactly same thing, but tell final result logic to the reader in a simple and clear manner: "Where is required should be all valid"

Comment: @Fabio in case of having some hundreds of criteria you are definitely right, but for simple and quite short cases my solution may be simpler.

Comment: From reader point of view 2-3 conditions can be ok, more is a pain to read if you want to understand the logic.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like a collection

```
public class Validation
{
    public bool Required { get; set; }
    public bool IsValid { get; set; }
}

var validations = new[]
{
    new Validation { Required = true, IsValid = true },
    new Validation { Required = false, IsValid = true },
    new Validation { Required = true, IsValid = false },
};

// return true only when all required validations are valid
public bool IsProductionReadyToStart()
{
    return _validations.Where(v => v.Required).All(v => v.IsValid);
}
```

Comment: Yes this looks to be the best approach, i have thought about it before but it requires to do some changes on my models and create a model to add validations

Comment: I think `validations` may should be a dictonary and not an array, or `Validation` should have somekind of id property or name.

Comment: Actually i have a table where the Required part can be set by the user. Now the number of options that can be validated are hard coded, this approach needs a table for validations

Comment: @Ackdari, not from the validation logic point of view. All validations have same priority.

Answer (score 5):

I'd go with:

```
if (IsComponentsRequired && !ValidateComponents) return false;
if (IsGeometriesRequired && !ValidatedGeometries) return false;
...
return true;
```

This reads more like a checklist.

Comment: I just like to keep things simple. I'm surprised voters seem to prefer additional "setup constructs" over simple statements - but I guess I'm getting old :)

Answer (score 5):

You may accumulate your conditions into [`ValueTuple`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple?view=netcore-3.1) collection, then check them all together

```cs
var conditions = new[]
{
    (IsComponentsRequired, ValidatedComponents),
    (IsGeometriesRequired, ValidatedGeometries),
    (IsPokayokesRequired, ValidatedPokayokes)
};

return conditions.Where(c => c.Item1).All(c => c.Item2);
```

You can also use [named tuple syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples#named-and-unnamed-tuples) for readability

```cs
var conditions = new (bool isRequired, bool validated)[]
{
    (IsComponentsRequired, ValidatedComponents),
    (IsGeometriesRequired, ValidatedGeometries),
    (IsPokayokesRequired, ValidatedPokayokes)
};

return conditions.Where(c => c.isRequired).All(c => c.validated);
```

Comment: What will be returned if all "isRequired" parts have the value false? i think the last like should look instead something like: ``return conditions.All(c => !c.isRequired || c.validated);``

Comment: @Fabio i know, and it was my intension. when you have no constraints, then everything is ok.

Comment: `.All` for empty collection returns `true`, so original code produces correct result for case when all components not required.

Answer (score 3):

Something I like to use is `&=`, it looks pretty clean but the downside is not everyone is familiar with this approach.

```
bool result = true;

result &= !IsComponentsRequired || IsComponentsRequired && ValidatedComponents;
result &= !IsGeometriesRequired|| IsGeometriesRequired && ValidatedGeometries;
//...etc
return result;
```

This code would function the same as:

```
result = result && (!IsComponentsRequired || IsComponentsRequired && ValidatedComponents);
//...etc
```

But I think it looks cleaner with the bitwise operation.

Comment: You solution could be simplified by removing the posivice condition and following && in each like e.g.: ``result &= !IsComponentsRequired || ValidatedComponents;`` instead of ``result &= !IsComponentsRequired || IsComponentsRequired && ValidatedComponents;``

Comment: I know, but I kept it like this because I find it more readable this way.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you really want is this:

```
return 
    (IsComponentsRequired && ValidatedComponents || IsComponentsRequired == false) &&
    (IsGeometriesRequired && ValidatedGeometries) || IsGeometriesRequired == false) &&
    (IsPokayokesRequired && ValidatedPokayokes || IsPokayokesRequired == false ) &&
    (IsTechnicalFileRequired && ValidatedTechnicalFile ||  IsTechnicalFileRequired == false) &&
    (IsStandardOperationSheetRequired && ValidatedStandardOperationSheet || IsTechnicalFileRequired == false) &&
    (IsOperationMethodRequired && ValidatedOperationMethod || IsOperationMethodRequired == false )
```

This can be implemented using reflection, so you don't need to change the code when adding more properties:

```
public class ProductionNavbarViewModel
{
    public bool IsProductionActive { get; set; }
    public bool ValidatedComponents { get; set; }
    public bool ValidatedGeometries { get; set; }
    public bool ValidatedPokayokes { get; set; }
    public bool ValidatedTechnicalFile { get; set; }
    public bool ValidatedStandardOperationSheet { get; set; }
    public bool ValidatedOperationMethod { get; set; }
    public bool IsComponentsRequired { get; set; }
    public bool IsGeometriesRequired { get; set; }
    public bool IsPokayokesRequired { get; set; }
    public bool IsTechnicalFileRequired { get; set; }
    public bool IsStandardOperationSheetRequired { get; set; }
    public bool IsOperationMethodRequired { get; set; }


    public bool IsProductionReadyToStart()
    {
        var validatedProps = this.GetType().GetProperties().Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("Validated"));
        foreach (var validatedProp in validatedProps)
        {
            var concept = validatedProp.Name.Substring(9);
            var isRequiredProp = this.GetType().GetProperty("Is" + concept + "Required");
            var isRequired = (bool)isRequiredProp.GetValue(this);
            if (isRequired)
            {
                var isValid = (bool)validatedProp.GetValue(this);
                if (isValid == false) return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```